# Difference between using Certificate based APN service VS Device Token APN service

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, sails.js

I'm a little confused on the difference between using Certificate based connections to the APN service verse the Device Token method.

My understanding is, when sending a push notification to an iOS device, my options are either:

***A) I could have registered the APN certificate with the Application bundle, and my provider can send it to the APN service to verify I'm allowed to send notifications to devices with that Application bundle.***

***B) My provider could be sent a "Device Token" via the downloaded application on the device over HTTP, and when I send that Device Token to the APN service, it will know the user has allowed me to send those notifications.***

My questions are:

***1) If I were to use method A, how could I target certain devices to send the notifications to if I don't have a device token?***

***2) If I use method B, where would I receive the device token to send silent notifications if my user "Doesn't Allow" push notifications? Will***

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
```

***Still run and allow me to pull the deviceToken out, so I can send it via HTTP to my provider?***

I've adopted a piece of software that used Certificate based Push Notifications (I think) and was unsure of how it was differentiating who to send notifications to with any deviceTokens. Once I rebuilt and redownloaded the application on my iOS device the notifications stopped working, so I assumed the certificate was no longer associated with the build.

I'm also curious as to how someone can debug notifications on a physical device. I've tried the Console app on Mac and have had little luck seeing any print statements I put in the code.

I'm still very new to iOS programming so please correct me if any of my understanding of the APN Service is wrong! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you want to use silent push notifications then enabling the remote notification background mode is sufficient to get a device token registration; you don't need to ask for notification permission; If you want to show push notifications then you need the permission, and if the user doesn't give permission then you don't have a token, but you don't need it.  You should register for it anyway since if the user subsequently changes the push notification permission in your app settings you will get a token next time your app launches

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to understand:

1. Your Company/Team's Certificate
2. Your App/Bundle's Provisioning profile
3. Your Client/User's Device Token
4. Your BackEnd Server

1 & 2 are bundled in your app when you upload it to App Store.

You get 3 when you ask user the permission for sending PN. [For this 2 should have the capability for *remote push notifications* enabled]

You give 1 & 3 to 4. [1 for establishing connection with APNS server, 3 to send PN to a specific iOS device]

So, to answer your question: **You need both A & B.**

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding how APNS works I am attaching a reference diagram that would help to clear your concept for the same.

[image: Push Notification LifeCycle and how it works]

** If I were to use method A, how could I target certain devices to send the notifications to if I don't have a device token?**

- Without Device token, you won't be able to target the iPhones or
  idevices on which you want to send the push notification

**if my user "Doesn't Allow" push notifications** -> then you won't be able to generate PUSH DEVICE TOKEN hence in this scenario you won't be able to receive any push notification.